# Rebaseable commits in git

Tags: git

How can I determine which commits can be safely rebased and which cannot?

I regularly maintain at least two remotes when contributing to a repository. One people can see (let's call it `origin`), and one that people can't see (`personal`). The `personal` remote is usually just a bare repo on some cloud drive where only I have access.

I do this because I want backup copies of my branches with the plan of interactively rebasing them before they are pushed for others to see. Given the following,

```
$ git log --oneline origin/master
bbbbbbb Commit B
aaaaaaa Commit A

$ git log --oneline origin/feature-C
ccccccc Commit C
bbbbbbb Commit B
aaaaaaa Commit A

$ git log --oneline origin/feature-D
ddddddd Commit D
bbbbbbb Commit B
aaaaaaa Commit A

$ git log --oneline personal/feature-Z
fffffff Commit F
eeeeeee Commit E
ddddddd Commit D
bbbbbbb Commit B
aaaaaaa Commit A
```

How can I execute a command, let's call it `rebaseable`, that gives me the following output?

```
$ git rebaseable personal/feature-Z
fffffff
eeeeeee
```

I would guess that I need to pass `origin` as some kind of parameter to tell the command that I want to compare against that remote. I want to know whether the commits covered by `personal/feature-Z` are anywhere in another remote, not just in one of the branches in that remote.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "rebaseable". Are you trying to figure out what commits are one one branch, but not on another, IE, which commits would be rebased? If so, that's not really a *rebasing* problem. There are many questions already asking how to find out which commits exist on branch A but not on branch B.

Comment: I don't mean just in one branch. I know it isn't purely a rebase problem from a technical standpoint, but from best practice I shouldn't rebase a commit that's been pushed somewhere so others can see it. I want to know whether the commits covered by this branch are anywhere in another remote.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the answer to your question.